# A design confusion about inheritance and interfaces

Tags: java

I'm stuck with a rather peculiar design problem. I'm using a Java ORM, and have defined one of my model classes as follows:

```
class User extends Model {
    // . . .
}
```

Now, there are more models, and I'd like them all to support data validations. The idea is simple: As each setter method is called, an internal `ArrayList` of errors keeps getting populated.

Now, the mechanism of error handling is exactly the same for all the model classes. I can envision the following interface:

```
public interface ErrorReportable {
    ArrayList<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

    boolean hasErrors();

    ArrayList<String> getErrors();

    void resetErrors();
}
```

Now I have a problem: All the methods are abstract, which means I'll have to provide an implementation for all of them in my classes. This is sad, because all these methods are going to be implemented in exactly the same way. Ideally, this would've been another class I would've neatly inherited from, but sadly, there's no multiple inheritance in Java.

My next option is use default methods in interfaces, but here the problem is the `errors` field, which will become static whereas I need a regular field for each instance.

It looks like the only solution is composition, but then I'll have to have a `hasErrors()` method on `User`, which will go `return this.error_obj.hasErrors()`. This is fine, but not really neat in my opinion as I'm having to write things twice.

How can I do better?

Comment: Do you really want validation to run immediately in setter? What if the setter is called twice, and provides invalid value at first but valid value in second call? Also, if you end up needing cross-field validations, validating in setters will become a nightmare.

Comment: @JiriTousek That won't happen, as far as I can tell. It's a typical web application, and the controller is going to populate fields one by one. At the end, the controller will call `hasErrors()` and send back the response to front-end. In the next cycle when the right data comes, a new object will be instantiated. But even if I choose to run the validation on demand, I think the design puzzle remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better for the model classes to only expose `List<Error> validate()` method, and to have a stand-alone validator that validates all the fields and collects the errors.

That way, the collected messages are not part of the model's state, you have explicit control over when will the validation happen, you're preferring composition (which is almost always a good thing), and the only method you need to implement in model class is the entity-specific validation.

If you ever need to add any cross-field validations, it will also be probably quite easy to extend this design to also perform those alongside with field validations.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I was convinced by the idea of cross-field validation. Since a model is going to have relationships, it will help if both the classes have an embedded validator.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your need right, I would implement an own Model-class, that implements all neceaasary Interfaces and extends the Model-ancestor, but still is Abstract.

Then all your normal model-classes inherit from your abstract model-class to get the implementation for the interface and also the inheritance from the model-class (2nd Generation would that be). Any framework checking with 'instance of' will still check true for the later model-class.

The abstract class does not even have to have any abstract methods/members, but it should stay abstract to prevent direct instanciating from that class.

```
public abstract class myModel extends Model implements ErrorReportable{ ... }

public class User extends myModel { ... }
```

Comment: Very nice! I feel this solution is almost there, but why an abstract class? None of the methods are going to be abstract. They will all have exactly the same implementation for all models. So I think if I define a normal class and it will do the trick?

Comment: If you want to prevent the myModel-class to be out there in the wild (since it maybe not Logical having an instance of myModel in usage over instances of class User) you would use an abstract class.
You don't need it to be abstract, but you can prevent calling the constructor of that design-class, that serves no aspect to have it as an instance out there.